# get redirect_to and flash notices to work after ajax form submission

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, redirect

Pushing a form submit button triggers an ajax post call from my application.js:

```
$("#form_div").on("click", "#submit_button", function() {

**code to capture data**

    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/units/",
         data: { 'var_1': var_1,
                 'var_2': var_2,},
         success:function(){
                alert("Details saved successfully!!!");
         },
         dataType: "text"
     });

     // stop normal form submission behaviour
     $("#add_DU_form").submit(function(e){
       return false;
     }); 
});
```

This calls the 'create' method in my rails controller (units_controller.erb) and a new record is successfully created.

```
def create

    ** code to create a new record **

    if @delivery_unit.save
        flash.notice = "Successfuly added"
        redirect_to :controller => "units", :action => "index", :id => params[var_1]
    end

end
```

The issue is that the flash notices and 'redirect_to' (called when a record is successfully created) do not work. I have to manually refresh the page to see flash notices and see the new record.

How can I get my flash notices and redirect to work? Thanks!

Comment: why are you submitting form using Ajax ?

Comment: I need to use ajax because the form is dynamically generated using javascript (i.e. is not contained in the DOM when the page is initially loaded). I couldn't get the form to submit without using ajax.

Comment: You don't need to use ajax in that case. If the form wasn't submitting normally, you probably did something wrong when creating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was quite a simple fix in the end.

If an AJAX call was submitted successfully, I simply redirected to a new URL in my application.js.

i.e.

```
$("#form_div").on("click", "#submit_button", function() {

    **code to capture data**

    // set URL to direct to upon successful AJAX call
    var redirect_url = "/units?op_session_id=" + op_session_id;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/units/",
        data: { 'var_1': var_1,
                'var_2': var_2,},
        success:function(){
            alert("Details saved successfully!!!");

            // redirect to new URL
            $(location).attr('href', redirect_url);
        },
        dataType: "text"
    });

    // stop normal form submission behaviour
    $("#add_DU_form").submit(function(e){
       return false;
    }); 
});
```

This also preserves the rails flash.notice functionality as flash notices are displayed when the page is next refreshed (i.e. when redirected to the new URL).

Comment: That last comment was exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect will change what the ajax call returns, but it won't do anything for page that makes the ajax request unless you tell it to. If you're getting the 'details saved successfully' alert, then that's all you can expect to happen.

If you absolutely must use ajax to submit the form, then you'll need to do something with javascript to handle the new record. Triggering a refresh might work for your purposes.

But if you don't need to use ajax here, then just don't use it, and the redirect should work.

Comment: yep i need to use ajax - see comment above. not sure a refresh will work as i want to redirect to another page. and clues on how to do that?